# I can't get this unsinged int to drop a value

Tags: c, encryption

Hey so i have a cipher program where the inputs look like this: e126,25,Byte. where the e stands for encrypt, 126 is assigned to lcg_m and 25 to lcg_c but my code

```
unsigned long readPositiveLong(char delimiter)
{
  unsigned long digits;
  char c;
  int count = 0;
  while( c = getchar() )
  {
    if( count == 0 )
    {
      digits = 0;
    }
    count++;
    if( c == delimiter )
    {
      return digits;
    }
    if( c != '0' && c != '1' && c != '2' && c != '3' && c != '4' && c != '5' &&
        c != '6' && c != '7' && c != '8' && c != '9' && c != delimiter)
    {
      return 0;
    }
    if( count > 20 )
    {
      return 0;
    }
    digits = digits * 10 + charToDigit(c);
  }
}
```

later in the code i call

```
lcg_m = readPositiveLong(,);
lcg_c = readPositiveLong(,);
```

This will give me the right lcg_m = 126 but when it gets to lcg_c i get 12625, so i was thinking it had to do with me not being able to reset digits to 0 but am unsure

Comment: `readPositiveLong(,);` or `readPositiveLong(',');` ?

Comment: ph well in my code i assigned a char g = ',' and put it as lcg_m = readPositiveLong(g) and lcg_c = readPositiveLong(g)

Comment: wow nm got, guess i cant use a variable in it

Comment: Note: Charge `if( c != '0' && ...  c != '9' && c != delimiter)` into `if((c < '0' || c > '9') && c != delimiter)`.  It is portable.  C requires `0` .. '9' top be consecutive.

Comment: Suggest `unsigned long digits = 0` to prevent UB.